# Fatal error in v8::Context::GetMicrotaskQueue: Must be called on a native context

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, vscode-debugger, deno

I want to attach VS Code's debugger with Deno. It runs fine if there is no breakpoint, but if there is then there is this error:

```bash
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/ws/bbf9166c-7c7c-4d0f-a55a-fd2acd54dee9
Visit chrome://inspect to connect to the debugger.
Deno is waiting for debugger to connect.
Debugger session started.

#
# Fatal error in v8::Context::GetMicrotaskQueue
# Must be called on a native context
#

Process exited with code 2147483651
```

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "type": "node",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.debug.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "C:\\Users\\ganuo\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WinGet\\Links\\deno.EXE",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "--unstable",
                "--inspect-wait",
                "--allow-all",
            ],
            "attachSimplePort": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely an issue in v1.35.2(linux)

**Downgrade like this :**

```
deno upgrade --version 1.35.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on the latest version of deno (v1.35.2) on Windows.

I downgraded to v1.34.3 and the problem went away so it is possibly a bug in the latest version.